# How to hide a folder from the URL using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to hide the "modules" folder from the url "www.domain.com/modules/demo/add.php"
I have written the following htaccess code,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^modules/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

After using the same .htaccess code, I found 404 error. (you can check the demo @ http://crmdemoserver.com/modules/demo/add.php

Comment: What do you mean by "hide" ? Your rule redirects modules/xxxx to /xxxx so when you access www.domain.com/modules/demo/add.php it tries to reach www.domain.com/demo/add.php. That's why you get a 404 error

Comment: If possible at all, try to place such protection and redirection rules in the main server configuration of your virtual host, _not_ inside '.htaccess' style files. Those files slow down the whole site considerably, are error prone and hard to debug.

Comment: So, is there any solution to hide the folder, as it is done in wordpress?

Comment: I don't want the user to let them know that the file is stored in modules folder

Answer (score 0):

Well you should think of it the other way around. Link this file only without the modules directory. In the .htaccess you can then simply do the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^demo/(.*)$ /modules/demo/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The .htaccess will be lying in the / directory.

Comment: I assumed that you already now how mod_rewrite works in general. If not look it up first. If you've done it, here's the explanation: you have the file linked as /demo/whatever/file and this rule rewrites to /demo/modules/whatever/file. In the address bar it still shows /demo/whatever/file.